# Leak in RuntimeBinder when using "dynamic" keyword with __ComObject

Tags: c#, dynamic, memory-leaks, comobject

Does anybody know if there is a way of preventing a memory leak in RuntimeBinder when using "dynamic" keyword with __ComObject instances in C#?

I got the following code:

```
var t = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("BB06C0E4-D293-4f75-8A90-CB05B6477EEE"));
while (true)
{
    dynamic o = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
}
```

This leaks LocalVariableSymbol class instances (and other from the Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics namespace).

Replacing "dynamic" with "object" i.e.:

```
    object o = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

fixes the leak but I'd prefer to keep using dynamic (the actual code is much more complex and makes use of "dynamic").

I know the RuntimeBinder singleton caches the data and this causes the leak but do you know if there's any way to cleanup the cache etc.?

Many thanks!

---

Similar questions:

- [Memory Overflow: Having an increasing number of Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080252/memory-overflow-having-an-increasing-number-of-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-s)
- [Memory leak in CLR classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757785/memory-leak-in-clr-classes)

Related links:

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1925659 (retired by Microsoft)
- https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2887

Comment: I've also raised a ticket for this on Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1925659

Comment: Did you found another solution ? I'm unable to use the object type

Comment: Unfortunately I got no news on this yet

Comment: I think I've found a way of using the "dynamic" keyword in the case with no memory leaks: "object o = Systen,Activator.CreateInstance(t); dynamic d = o;" and then use d as usual. Have checked this with a memory profiler and it no longer reports the leaks.

Comment: I will try, but in my case, I don't have any call to CreateInstance, I only have public static field of type Dynamic. So not sure where to put this additional step

Comment: I think you can try to lookup for the dynamic static field assignments in your code and then replace any direct assignments like "MyClass.TheStaticDynamicField = ..." with a "object o = ...; MyClass.TheStaticDynamicField = o;". I've checked this with a static field (instead of a local variable) and it no longer leaks for me with the workaround however I got no idea why this fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm currently trying to remove most of the dynamic. I replaced all the static registration as "dynamic"(since it's more when I used them that I need to have their exact implementation). I'm almost done. I think after that I will have to make that my methods receive an object/some-more-generic-interface and then typecast it as dynamic to see if that solve the issue.

Comment: I tried your proposal, for me it doesn't change anything for now. I also tried to do stuff only in non-anonymous method(I think that the callSite maybe different otherwise)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution in my case was to replace:

```
dynamic o = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

with:

```
object o = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
dynamic d = o;
```

The memory leak no longer occurs having the workaround applied.

Comment: **That actually works!** In one case I'm aware of, changing method signature from `void Foo(dynamic x) { ... }` to `void Foo(object x) { dynamic y = x; ... }` did the trick.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem: Using "dynamic" caused a memory leak.

I solved this in the following way:

```
using (dynamic attr = curve.Attributes)
{
  if (attr != null)
    return attr.InternalLabel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robert however it's not going to work for me because __ComObject does not implement IDisposable.